# Child component doesn't get updated when props changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, axios

I am having trouble understanding how vue js's reactivity work. I am trying to make a component for all kinds of ajax call, the problem is when I change the props to be passed on to the component it doesn't get the changes in the data.

https://jsfiddle.net/8t4vx44r/34/

```js
Vue.component('api-call-template', {
 template: '#api-call-templates',
 props: {
      apiCallParams: Object
    },
  data () {
    return {
      result: [],
      loading: false
    }
  },
  created() {
   console.log("entered?")
    console.log(this.apiCallParams);
      var vm = this;
      vm.loading = true;
      axios({
         method: this.apiCallParams.method,
         url: this.apiCallParams.url,
         data: this.apiCallParams.params
       }).then(function(response) {
        vm.result = response.data;
        vm.loading = false;
        vm.$emit('get-response', response);
      });
       console.log(vm.loading)
}
});

var vm = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
  apiCallParams: {
      url: '',
      method: '',
      params: {}
    },
    author: 'aa'
 },
  created() {
   this.apiCallParams.url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users/1';
   this.apiCallParams.method = 'get';
    console.log("passing this");
    console.log(this.apiCallParams);
  },
  methods: {
    search() {
    console.log("searching")
  this.url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users/2';
   this.apiCallParams.method = 'get';
    },
    getResponse(response) {
     console.log("back to parent");
     console.log(response);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
try {{title}}
  <post :title="title" :author="author" :content="content">
   
  </post>
</div>

<template id="post-template">
 <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
 <h4>{{ author }}</h4>
 <p>{{ content }}</p>
</template>
```

If you click the "next user button" it updates the data in the parent component but it doesn't call my api-call-template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only calling one time because your logic is at `created()`, which is called only once (when the component is created).

Considering your component is:

```
<api-call-template :api-call-params="apiCallParams" @get-response="getResponse">...
```

And you want to request every time `api-call-params` changes. What you could do is:

- Move your logic from `created()` to a method, say `performRequest()`
- Call `this.performRequest()` on `created()`
- Add a watcher to `apiCallParams` prop
- Call `this.performRequest()` on `apiCallParams` watcher

See demo below.

```js
Vue.component('api-call-template', {
  template: '#api-call-templates',
  props: {
    apiCallParams: Object
  },
  data() {
    return {
      result: [],
      loading: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    performRequest() {
      console.log("entered?")
      console.log(this.apiCallParams);
      var vm = this;
      vm.loading = true;
      axios({
        method: this.apiCallParams.method,
        url: this.apiCallParams.url,
        data: this.apiCallParams.params
      }).then(function(response) {
        vm.result = response.data;
        vm.loading = false;
        vm.$emit('get-response', response);
      });
      console.log(vm.loading)
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.performRequest();
  },
  watch: {
    apiCallParams() {
      this.performRequest();
    }
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    apiCallParams: {
      url: '',
      method: '',
      params: {}
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.apiCallParams = {url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users/1', method: 'get'}
    console.log("passing this");
    console.log(this.apiCallParams);
  },
  methods: {
    search() {
      console.log("searching")
      this.apiCallParams = {url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users/2', method: 'get'};
    },
    getResponse(response) {
      console.log("back to parent");
      console.log(response);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="search">next user</button>
  <api-call-template :api-call-params="apiCallParams" @get-response="getResponse"></api-call-template>
</div>

<template id="api-call-templates">
  <div>
    <main>
      <div v-if="loading">loading</div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
          <div v-for="res in result" :key="res.id">
            <div class="col-md-4 cards">
              <div>
                results
                <h3>{{ res.first_name }}</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>
```

There is only one ***caveat:*** to trigger the watch, change `apiCallParams` at once, like:

```
this.apiCallParams = {url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users/2', method: 'get'};
```

**Not** property by property, like:

```
this.apiCallParams.url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users/2';      // don't do like this
this.apiCallParams.method = 'get';                             // don't do like this
```

As Vue won't pick up changes if you do it prop by prop.